# Solving for $x$ in $M ^ {M ^ M} = x ^ {1 / (x-1)}$ where $M = 5 ^ {\sqrt{5} / 10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, lambert-w, power-towers

Methods used by analogy, for example $x ^ x = 3 ^ 3 \implies x = 3$,

> Determine the value of $x$ in
>   $$M ^ {M ^ M} = x ^ {1 / (x-1)}$$
>   if $M = 5 ^ {\sqrt{5} / 10}$.

Comment: Maple answers $x=2.55849460788022014674343500422 $.

Comment: I think a good starting point is to recognize that $M$ can be written as $\sqrt{5}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}}$

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure how you're supposed to spot the solution here, but one may solve this equation for $x$ using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) as follows:

$$C=M^{M^M}=x^{1/(x-1)}\\C^{x-1}=x\\\frac1C=xC^{-x}\\\frac1C=xe^{-\ln(C)x}\\-\frac{\ln(C)}C=-\ln(C)xe^{-\ln(C)x}\\W_k\left(-\frac{\ln(C)}C\right)=-\ln(C)x$$

> $$x=-\frac{W_k(-\ln(C)/C)}{\ln(C)}$$

which admits [two different real solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2871935). Since $-\ln(C)/C=\ln(1/C)e^{\ln(1/C)}$, one of these solutions simplifies down to $x=1$, which is an extraneous solution. The other is non-trivial and may simplify, though it is not obvious to me.

Comment: Do you think the question is a PSQ? If you do then try not to give a full answer, even though I see that you've been quite into the Lambert W function lately :)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I do, though it's old and I'm trying to remove it from the unanswered list. (One may also wish to see the OP's profile)

Comment: Mhm... In any case do as you wish with them.